# MongoDB filter with date is not returning any result with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, date, filter, find

I am using C# with Visiual studio 2015/ MongoDB C# drivers NuGET package. I am facing issues with filtring and sorting on date.

I have created following MetricBatch class

```
class MetricsBatch
{
    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public MongoDB.Bson.BsonDateTime BatchStartTime { get; set; }
    public MongoDB.Bson.BsonDateTime    BatchEndTime { get; set; }
    public string MetricsType { get; set; }
}
```

I have created object "objMetricsBatch" of this class  and inserted in MongoDB

```
var batchCollection = _database.GetCollection<MetricsBatch>("MetricsBatch");
batchCollection.InsertOneAsync(objMetricsBatch);
```

It gets inserted successfully as I can see the records If I am not using any filter however when I am putting following date filter not getting any result, I tried number of options however no success.

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonDateTime strtDate = new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) )
var filter2 = Builders<MetricsBatch>.Filter.Gte("TradeBatchStartTime", strtDate);
var result2 = await apmMetricsCollection.Find<MetricsBatch>( filter2 ).ToListAsync();
```

There were no results are getting return, not sure why.  I have also tried sort of the date however that also not seems to be working.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I checked my code further and found following, in filter below I put the field name as "TradeBatchStartTime" instead of "BatchStartTime".  Surprisingly MangoDB or MangoDB  driver for C#  doesnt give any error.  I am not sure on reason behind it that why MangoDB doesnt give warning or error.  Or may be that it is some bug in C# MangoDB driver.

Now trying to check that how I can put relationship between MangoDB documents and bit on aggrigation.

var filter2 = Builders.Filter.Gte("TradeBatchStartTime", strtDate);

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the problem of MongoDB C# driver. As MongoDB is NoSQL Database, so there is not any specific schema for the databases. And thus, in First code when you were searching with 'TradeBatchStartTime' field, Query is trying to find that "Is there any document which contain 'TradeBatchStartTime' field with value greater than value of 'startDate' ?" But, as there is not any field named 'TradeBatchStartTime' in database so query return no result.

And as you are using POCO model and if you want type safety then you could use another overload of Gte filter definition which uses LINQ. As below:

```
var filter2 = Builders<MetricsBatch>.Filter.Gte(x=>x.BatchStartTime , strtDate);
```

Now it will a compile time error if you compare with 'TradeBatchStartTime' field instead of 'BatchStartTime'.
  Hope this will help.